# Orders table, distinguish between "take-away orders" and "orders for a table"

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

```
Products: id (PK) | name
Orders: id (PK) | sale_date
Products_orders: order_id (FK) | product_id (FK) | quantity | price
```

I have to distinguish an order: it can be **an order to a specific table** or a **take-away order**, so that I could output something like this:

"*The order number 10 is for table number 23, in that table there are 5 people (so this order is for 5 people, bring 5 drinking glasses)*"

"*The order number 11 is a take-away order for John*"

As you can see, the "**orders table**" just needs to store **table number** and **the number of people that are on that table currently**; "**take-away orders**" just needs to store **the name of the person who "booked" the order** (just the name, they told me they don't want surname and the time, just the name).

How can I to implement that to Orders table? I thought to make the table in this way:

```
Orders: id (PK) | sale_date | table_number (INT) | n_people_in_table (INT) | take_away_name (VARCHAR)
```

so if the order is for a table I would populate the "table_number" and "n_people_in_table" fields, and the "take_away_name" would be be NULL. Otherwise, if the order is a take-away order, I would populate "take_away_name"; "table_number" and "n_people_in_table" fields would be NULL.

But I don't like this solution very much and I don't think it is an elegant way. Which is the best way to do that?

## EDIT:

as requested, here's sample data:

**Products**:

| id (PK) | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | banana |

**Orders**:

| id (PK) | sale_date |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2022/07/18 21:05:00 |
| 11 | 2022/07/18 21:15:00 |

**Products_orders**:

| order_id (FK) | product_id (FK) | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 3.40 |
| 11 | 2 | 10 | 2.50 |

How can I to store the fact that order 10 was for table number 23 and it was for 5 people?
How can I to store the fact that order 11 was a take-away order for a man "John"?

Comment: Instead of a single `orders` table, have one for "orders for a table" (`orders_table`) and one for "orders for takeaway" (`orders_takeaway`). They would each contain columns relevant to their role: `orders_table` would have `table_number` and `n_people_in_table` columns, while `orders_takeaway` would have only a `take_away_name` column. The only difficulty here would be if you want to change a "for a table" order to a "takeaway" order, or vice-versa.

Comment: @kmoser thank you for the reply, but in **products_orders** how can I handle the foreign key? Currenlty it has "order_id (FK)" field that is reference to **orders** table

Comment: Split `products_orders` into two tables (`table_products_orders` and `takeaway_products_orders`) and have `order_id` be a FK into the corresponding parent table.